# Debugger Keeps Flagging Me f/ a Cells Select Code

Tags: excel, vba, select, copy-paste

I keep getting flagged for the "Cells(NewestEntry, 1).Select" line. I got that section of code from using a Macro, but it used "Cells(A1).Select" and I need to use coordinates in order to use the "NewestEntry" string. I don't know how to get around this problem?

```
Dim Tail As ArrayList
Set Tail = New ArrayList

Dim DesiredTail As String
Dim FirstLine As String
Dim NewestEntry As String

   FirstLine = 6
   NewestEntry = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))
   
For i = 0 To 20 Step 3 'Tail #/Number of Tails
    DesiredTail = Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(i + 6, 3).Value
    Tail.Add DesiredTail

Next i

For j = 0 To 3 'Tail Tabs/Number of Tabs

    For k = 1 To 3 '# of Entries to Grab
      
        Sheets(Tail(j)).Select
        Cells(NewestEntry, 1).Select
        Selection.Copy
            Sheets("StepBrief").Select
            Range(FirstLine, 4).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
        NewestEntry = NewestEntry - 1
        FirstLine = FirstLine + 1

        Next k
        FirstLine = FirstLine + 1
    Next j
```

Comment: The `Max` function returns a `Double`, not a `String`, so change the declaration of `NewestEntry` to that instead of `String`. The error indicated would arise if you tried to select a cell on "row 0", i.e. does `NewestEntry` ever reach 0?

Comment: @SpectralInstance The NewestEntry is supposed to find the most recent date in column A on Sheets(Tail(j)).

Comment: That would still be a numeric data type. What is that value (of NewestEntry) when your code runs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SpectralInstance That was a little helpful! I changed it to a double. The NewestEntry is pulling from the Sheet StepBrief Tab but not Sheets(Tail(j)) which is what I need it to do. I've heard I shouldn't use select or activate, but I don't know what else I would use.

Comment: @SpectralInstance In the `NewestEntry = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))` I tried replacing WorksheetFunction with the Tail J.  `Application.Sheets(Tail(j)).Max(Columns("A"))`. It said it was out of range?

Comment: `Tail(j)` doesn't exist at the time you assign a value to `NewestEntry`. If it should come from a specific sheet, and looking at where `Tail(j)` will come from, I think your syntax should be something like `NewestEntry =  Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets(Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(6, 3).Value).Columns("A"))`

Comment: You can also avoid the `Select`s and consolidate your copying/pasting with this single line `Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(NewestEntry, 1).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 4)`

Comment: @SpectralInstance I noticed that! I tried moving the location of NewestEntry in the K For Loop, but its still reading from StepBrief. I tried your method for the NewestEntry and it still didnt work. It gave me a runtime error 9, Subscript out of range. Concerning your 2nd comment IM POSITIVE I tried that method already! but it did stop flagging me, but its not pasting anything in the cells.

Comment: If you got an error 9 then that means that you don't have a worksheet named for `Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(6, 3).Value` ?

Comment: @SpectralInstance The value of that cell does = a Tab Name. Im angerily looking at it right now.  I appreciate your help and time! Its ok, ill keep trying to figure it out, unless you have any other ideas.

Comment: I'm afraid that I would need to be able to see your worksheet names, and a screenshot of your data (incl row numbers and column headers) to be able to provide further insights.